# CAML query where to get all items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I am going to implement a search query. I have 2 inputs user can give value or leave as empty.
If user leave both input as empty and Search,,all items must populated. 
here I have static SP CAML query string. With 2 variables. but any variable can empty. When that variable empty I want to ignore that where part and get values. How can I do it?

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Title" />
                <Value Type="Text">var1</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Subchannel" />
                <Value Type="Text">var2</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
     </Where>
</Query>
```

When `var1` is empty I want to ignore that where condition. If both `var1` and `var2` is empty I want to get all items from list.

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript

```
var query="Your Query here";if(var1=="" && var2!=""){query="First Query";}if(var1=="" && var2==""){query="Second Query";}if(var1!="" && var2!=""){query="Third Query";}
```

for returning all results you can use * as query term

Comment: I want to use one static query string. and '*' is not working in CAMl query builder.